# Performance Issue On Render In ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, state, render

From what I'm reading, desired practice for working with form elements and state update is following:

```
onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        name:event.target.value
    })
}
```

where above is event handler for a input field:

```
<input 
    type="text"
    onChange={this.onChange}
    value={this.state.name}
/>
```

And this is how we keep state updated, and also input field itself.

Now if we put a console.log(new Date()) inside render function, we can observe that render is called on each key press in input field.

My **question is, can this cause a performance issue**, actually if there are known cases when this can cause performance issue? 
Also, isn't there any better way, this updating-state-re-rendering doesn't seem to be most efficient?

**Edit 1:** Imagine complex form control, lots of complex form items that can be further more complex controls,... So this input is inside of this complex component that is timely to render. Now, can you expect(did ever happened to you), that re-rendering on state update(while typing) to cause performance issue (visible lag).

Comment: you can also use shouldComponentUpdate.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: Thanks Edward, I am aware of it, in this case we do want update basically as response to updated state.

Comment: In that case I'd just recommend using onBlur instead of on change to minimize number of rerenders otherwise it shouldn't be an issue. If you are experiencing slowness that might be due too something else or you simply have way too many elements to render

Comment: Thank you again, I don't think I expressed my self in the right way. I don't need a fix for any behavior of my app, it is just a hypothetical question. I was just curious about other developers experience.

Comment: My apologies I didn't understand you correctly. In that case I'd say yes, it's possible, but when you have a very large number of elements to render.

Answer (score 0):

This is how React is built. See official [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

You can use web inspector and type to check what’s being re-rendered and that’s only the text input box.

Yes it gets called *every time* you type, but only what’s being changed *actually* re-renders.

Comment: As I understand render method will re-render whole component whose state was updated, not just input box.

Comment: The state gets checked for differences, and only the differences are re-rendered. Go to the last section of this [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html), you can see that only the text of the `h2` tag is re-rendered.
See this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/singleinput-i50k2) and start typing on the input box: only the `value` prop is re-rendered.

Comment: Hey leverglowh, thanks a lot for the effort! I understand what are you saying, but if you have more controls in your return(), it will all got re-rendered, and imagine those are all complex components. Check my edit of the question, I am just curious on the hypothetical situation. Actually I wanted to know if you/anybody had any experience where this way of functioning caused you a lag with the interface behavior?

Comment: Actually, yes. It can have performance issues like in [this article](https://marmelab.com/blog/2017/02/06/react-is-slow-react-is-fast.html) I found. And yes react is aware of that hence [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/6oxkg8/how_to_handle_states_that_are_constantly_updated/dklbsd9?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).